# Developing mobile website in sencha touch without mvc

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to develope my mobile website in sencha without using mvc framework. I have to fetch the data from API and feed it into UI. Can you please tell me structure to use for it.

Comment: I have the feeling I _may_ be able to help but I simply don't understand the question.

Comment: MVC shouldn't be an issue with what you're trying to accomplish and honestly it's worthwhile to learn MVC, especially with Sencha.

Comment: isn't Sencha touch an MVC itself?

Comment: It think you could place all code in app.js and use Ext.create instead of Ext.define but I wouldn't recommend it...